# USB device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, usb, usb-drive, gpio

I Wrote a USB device driver for STM32h7 and register the device as GPIO by using Struct gpio_chip structure. my questions are here:

I configure usb peripheral in NUCLEO-H743ZI board to CUSTUM HID CLass of communication by QUBE-MX . I mean communication between linux usb dirver and device's usb port is done in this class. 
is it true for this type of comunication?

When I export the GPIO for example gpio496 into kernel space with below command:

```
echo 496 > /sys/class/gpio
```

and then I want to set direction with

```
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio496
```

the process is killed and my ubuntu hangs and the device being connected after unplugging the device.

what is my problem? [image]

Answer (score 0):

> I Wrote a USB device driver for STM32h7 and register the device as GPIO by using Struct gpio_chip structure. my questions are here:

I would assume your wrote a kernel land driver (.ko) ... do you ?

> When I export the GPIO for example gpio496 into kernel space with below command:
>   echo 496 > /sys/class/gpio
>   and then I want to set direction with
>   echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio496

Reading [this doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt), it looks like you're right.

> the process is killed and my ubuntu hangs and the device being connected after unplugging the device.
>   what is my problem?

Problably kernel panic or kernel oops resulting of an error on your device driver code.
To confirm/have more details, try to:
1. launch your test directly from a text console (ctrl-alt+F1 should work): since the kernel will dump its error on console, you'll see it.
*or*
2. dump your kernel logs into a terminal windows using, as root, `cat /dev/kmsg`.

Note that 2. may not work depending on several factors... prefer 1. if you can.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was sending bulk data with an Interrupt endpoint.